# Logistics of job offer negotiation

Tags: united-states, job-search, salary, negotiation

My question about the logistics of negotiating academic job offers (in particular salary) is two-folded. Is it best:

1. to simply point which items of an offer can the department improve on (e.g. salary, startup package, relocation) or be specific about a range of values that I have in mind for each item?
2. to do so in a Zoom meeting or by e-mail?

Naturally, I imagine that giving some justification for the increases would be necessary either orally or via e-mail.

EDIT: the question is for the US academic job market. The offer comes from the dean but my contact is a department faculty heading the search committee.

Comment: Country? Who is your contact and who has decisionmaking power on the offer? For instance, at my uni, offers came from the dean, but my contact was my chair. So basically it was the chair’s job to help me frame my counter to the dean.

Comment: @Dawn good points. I edited the question to stress that the context of my question is the US job market and the offer came from the dean but my contact is the faculty member heading the search committee.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest having everything in writing (which would suggest email) and to be specific (which would suggest providing concrete numbers or ranges for the items you would like to negotiate).

Being nonspecific (e.g., saying "the salary you offer is too low") is just not a great starting point for a conversation. Of course you want more salary. We all do. So inevitably whoever you talk to will have to ask you (i) what "not too low" would mean, (ii) why you think you have a basis for negotiation, such as an offer from elsewhere. You might as well avoid this round of statement-and-question by saying up front what you want and why you want it.